# Firebase Android - Writing data to the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database:

[image: 1]

I want the `latitude`, `longitude`, and `id` keys inside `QBMR...` to get overwritten, but instead three new nodes are being created outside `QBMR...`.

This is my code for writing data to the database:

[image: Code for the database]

`mUserRef` refers to the "Users" node, and `idRef` refers to `QBMR...`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't believe you need to add the user id to the hashmap if you are already creating a reference with the user id.

Comment: Oh yeah I am going to remove the user id. Main problem I am having is the lat and long are being created as separate nodes.

Comment: Try dropping the forward slash. Just try `"latitude"` and `"longitude"`